# Function prototypes when delay loading a DLL

Tags: c++

I'm delay loading a DLL as described [here](http://www.goffconcepts.com/techarticles/development/cpp/calldll.html). The DLL comes with a .h file that has both constant definitions and function declarations. This means that when I try to do

```
MyFunction = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID);  // See link above
```

The compiler complains "error: cannot convert 'int (*)(int, int, int)' to 'int(int, int, int)' in assignment" because MyFunction was already declared like so in the .h file:

```
int __stdcall MyFunction (int, int, int);
```

Should I:

A) Comment out the function prototypes in the .h file and create my own using

```
typedef int (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(int, int, int);
pICFUNC MyFunction;
MyFunction = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID);
```

B) Do the same as A) but give the function a different name (MyFunction_local) instead of commenting out the prototypes in the .h file.

C) Something else that I haven't thought of.

I'd like to do A), but it feels wrong to be messing with a third-party .h file like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's bad news to have two symbols with the same name but different meanings. Your option B, using a different name for the local pointer, sounds like the best solution.

If you insist on using the same name for both the function and the pointer, you could put one or the other into a namespace.